# Как исправить ошибку require is not defined?

Tags: javascript

На сайте используется js плагин jQuery Validation Plugin, в котором есть такие строчки:

```
(function( factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
        define( ["jquery"], factory );
    } else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory(require( "jquery" ));
    } else {
        factory( jQuery );
    }
}(function( $ ) {

$.extend( $.fn, {...
```

В результате браузер выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Тестирую сайт на openserver, винда.

Подозреваю, ошибка из-за nodejs.

**P.S.**
вот этот файл:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.16.0/dist/jquery.validate.js
Добавлю ещё что используется Vitejs в Laravel проекте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: во первых код не весь, во вторых хотелось бы прям на ошибку посмотреть, а не отрывок из контекста...

Comment: @Maneken, добавил комментарий